# Creating APIs with nested class methods (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, nested, typescript-class

I'm trying to create a typescript class that wraps a REST api, and i'd like to organize the various methods into sub objects for better expressibility of the code. any way of doing so and still maintaining access to the class instance via 'this' from whithin the methods?

for example consider the following class:

```
class ApiService {
  constructor() {....}

  getMedia() {}

  uploadMedia() {}

  sendMassage() {}

  recieveMessage() {}

}
```

I'd like to organize the above methods so that i'd be able to call them like so:

```
const service = new ApiService();
//to call getMedia()
service.media.get();
//to call sendMessage()
service.messages.send();
// and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

I think to achieve what you're asking for exactly as stated, you should use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) so that the `apiService.media` and `apiService.message` objects don't have their own `this` context to get in the way.  For example:

```
class ApiService {

    constructor(public name: string) { }

    private getMedia() { 
        console.log(this.name+" getMedia");
    }

    private uploadMedia() { 
        console.log(this.name+" uploadMedia");
    }

    private sendMassage() { 
        console.log(this.name+" sendMessage");
    }

    private recieveMessage() { 
        console.log(this.name+" receiveMessage");
    }

    // instance methods
    public media = {
        get: () => this.getMedia(),
        upload: () => this.uploadMedia()
    }

    // instance methods
    public message = {
        send: () => this.sendMassage(),
        receive: () => this.recieveMessage()
    }

}
```

Note that this means that each instance of `ApiService` will have its own copy of the function-valued properties `message.send` etc.  They will not sit on the `ApiService.prototype` like normal methods.  This shouldn't matter much unless you are spawning many instances of `ApiService`.

Let's make sure it works and is bound correctly:

```
const api1 = new ApiService("One");
const api2 = new ApiService("Two");

api1.message.receive(); // One recieveMessage
api2.message.receive(); // Two receiveMessage

api1.media.get(); // One getMedia
api2.media.get(); // Two getMedia
```

Looks good.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAECCAOBLAygUwE4DdHFdA3gFDTTAD2AdhAC7oCuw1Z6AFPHQEYg7QVgC2qAFzQa6RBQDmASgIBfQsWjxxmMNTyTU1ALKoAJojAtZREiXJUyIVADoQZSS2oALRBFt9B0ANTQARNBaugZG-tIA3EoKSiqIahrQdPAOYPp6hsamShaUENZ2Dk6u7p4CeH6ByanpoWDhUSQxJHEJeBCoFOmQEGBaJgQ5pHkF9o7Obh5eFQGinbVQfagN0Yotqup46KjAiKiYqHqL-dnmw1Y2Y8WTZd6V0Nu48Yeox8uRq0oA9F-QEjRgCi4aCCVxkfQQWKcbjAEF1aAAXkGZ2CIgGCIAfNASh5ghkjCYADRDapkNJo2SY7E3UlpfFZaJRb6-f7UQHA0EucGQlrQniCN6I5HmDpdCmIrE42yi7pvIlDR6oZ7iqlSx57A5HXonRmEGKWGjQMBIACMQooqAA7nAkGgsDhUCx-AB5C0rA3UI1IABM5qtNpQGGwuCdABVLWQVoRjYgTbYBdq7IrniYItAftBXVsdhqXm9oz7469E7ZkwdU+nfuGyA8dkrNcWlooY3HBJlbMEKxms0FtPSC4hvUX253IpXoNXeyFMoQgA)

Comment: thanks, it works but has it's drawbacks - the nested methods lose their intellisense and additional info,on the one hand the code is more expressive, on the other less clarity...

Comment: "the nested methods lose their intellisense" That's news to me.  Can you demonstrate this?